# Exporting a Chart into RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a page on which client has a Chart. Now this chart needs to be put in an RDLC report.
I have collected the image of the chart in System.Drawing.Image but don't know how to put this in RDLC.

Comment: Are you trying to add a static image to the report? Or are you trying to programmatically add an image to the report at runtime? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Yes I wanted to add image but I did that in some other way.

Comment: Can you share the way you were able to do it (as an answer)?

Answer (score 0):

I bind the image to one of the column and then bind that to data set to fetch image into RDLC report.
Here is the code...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn("chart");
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");
        dt.Columns.Add(column);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        //Saving the Image of Graph into memory stream
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        byte[] ByteImage = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(ByteImage, 0, (int)ms.Length);


        dr["chart"] = ByteImage;
        string s = dr[0].ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",dt));
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest following.

1. Create RDLC report for that chart by passing the same things that you are using to draw the chart on that page. This approach is really helpful for you, you can modify it according to your client requirements.
2. You can set image to RDLC. Use RDLC image control. Pass image **full path** to dataset that you will use in your RDLC report.